# AWS: How do I continuously deploy a static website on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, web-hosting, continuous-deployment

I have a github repo with *static* website contents (i.e I try not to use EC2, but the AWS static website service). Now I want to automatically deploy it on AWS anytime I change and push something to the master branch of my github repo.

Any experience or idea doing this?

Comment: Amazon S3 is a good choice for serving static website contents.

Answer (score 1):

I do this for many projects by using a Jenkins server - I happen to run it on another ec2 instance, but you could also run it on-premise if you prefer.

Github notifies Jenkins server that a checkin has occurred, and a Jenkins job deploys all the files to the proper places and also notifies me by SMS (or email), that a deployment has occurred.

(Jenkins is not the only tool that can do this there are others).